# SQL Alchemy spending too much time in preparing the query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a simple query like

```
query = session.query(table.video_id).
        join(VideoCatalog, VideoCatalog.id == table.video_id).
        filter(table.event_code.in_(event_codes)).
        filter(rec.video_id.in_(input_video_ids))
result = query.all()
```

`input_video_ids is a long list of 100k values`

I have observed that sqlalchemy is taking more than 2 seconds to just parse the query. This is more than the time it takes for my query to run on the database.

To make it more clear the following is taking 2 seconds to run

```
query = session.query(table.video_id).
        join(VideoCatalog, VideoCatalog.id == table.video_id).
        filter(table.event_code.in_(event_codes)).
        filter(rec.video_id.in_(input_video_ids))
```

I tried profiling this piece of code, and I observed that the following lines consume most of the time.

```
         4668894 function calls (4668876 primitive calls) in 2.736 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        3    0.000    0.000    2.735    0.912 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py:218(operate)
        3    0.000    0.000    2.735    0.912 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/properties.py:366(operate)
      8/2    0.000    0.000    2.735    1.367 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py:515(in_)
        4    0.000    0.000    2.735    0.684 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:758(operate)
      6/2    0.000    0.000    2.735    1.367 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/operators.py:1261(in_op)
        4    0.000    0.000    2.735    0.684 <string>:1(<lambda>)
        4    0.001    0.000    2.735    0.684 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py:64(operate)
        2    0.222    0.111    2.734    1.367 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/default_comparator.py:158(_in_impl)
   179533    0.256    0.000    2.089    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:4218(_bind_param)
   179533    0.764    0.000    1.833    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:961(__init__)
   179534    0.353    0.000    0.555    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:4402(__new__)
   179533    0.081    0.000    0.291    0.000 /usr/lib/python3.7/re.py:185(sub)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.286    0.143 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:1991(__init__)
        2    0.102    0.051    0.286    0.143 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:2001(<listcomp>)
   179534    0.118    0.000    0.182    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:4354(__new__)
   179533    0.082    0.000    0.159    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/type_api.py:559(coerce_compared_value)
   897732    0.126    0.000    0.126    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
   179533    0.072    0.000    0.121    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:4744(_is_literal)
   179537    0.033    0.000    0.119    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:4666(_expression_literal_as_text)
   179533    0.082    0.000    0.108    0.000 /usr/lib/python3.7/re.py:271(_compile)
   179533    0.101    0.000    0.101    0.000 {method 'sub' of 're.Pattern' objects}
   179537    0.036    0.000    0.086    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:4686(_literal_as_text)
   179533    0.058    0.000    0.077    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py:3011(_resolve_value_to_type)
   179537    0.065    0.000    0.065    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:706(self_group)
   179537    0.029    0.000    0.050    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:4670(_literal_as)
   179541    0.042    0.000    0.042    0.000 {built-in method __new__ of type object at 0xa21aa0}
   179555    0.021    0.000    0.021    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
   179544    0.020    0.000    0.020    0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
   179549    0.019    0.000    0.019    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
   179533    0.019    0.000    0.019    0.000 {built-in method builtins.id}
   179533    0.018    0.000    0.018    0.000 {method 'strip' of 'str' objects}
   179538    0.016    0.000    0.016    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
```

I also tried preparing the raw query and issuing an `session.execute(Raw Query)`. It doesn't consume this extra 2 seconds. That is why I suspect it has to something with sqlalchemy's preprocessing.
`Sqlalchemy version = 1.3.17`

Is there any way to optimize this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The versions of SQLAlchemy and Python in use are both quite old.  Later versions of Python and SQLAlchemy (1.4.x) have performance improvements, so it might be worth profiling the statement on the latest versions of both.

Comment: @snakecharmerb it worked. Updating sqlalchemy to V1.4 helped a lot. Query preparation time went from 2.5 seconds to 0.06 seconds. Thank you very much